# Teradata: How can you add an identity column to an existing table?

Tags: alter-table, teradata, identity-column

I need to add an identity column to an existing table with this SQL:

```
alter table app.employee 
add ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 100000000 NO CYCLE)
```

I can create new tables with an identity column just fine, but the above script gives me the following error:

> `ALTER TABLE Failed. 3706: Syntaxt error: Cannot add new Identity
>   Column option`

Teradata database is severely lacking in online support and I've only come across one option which is to basically create a copy of the table with the identity column and do a mass insert from the old table to the new one and change all references to the new table.  I find it difficult to believe that this is the only possible way to do this.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are online resources for Teradata such as SO, Database Administrators (Stack Exhcange), and the Teradata Developer Exchange. Those are probably your best sources of information.

Page 43 of the Teradata *SQL Data Definition Language - Detailed Topics* Manual for Teradata 13.10 states:

> You can not add an identity column to an existing base table, nor can
>   you add the identity column attribute to an existing column.

It may seem tedious but this approach works very well and minimizes the down time of the data for the end users. It works well and is the preferred method that we use when making data model changes against tables with billions of rows. The insert of data into the new table should be fairly well optimized as the Teradata optimizer should opt for a data block level MERGE operation instead of row by row.

1. Create new table with Identity Column
2. Make sure target table changes to original table are held.
3. Insert Select data from old table into new table.
4. Rename {orig_table} as {orig_table}_old.
5. Rename {new_table} as {orig_table}.
6. Validate new table's data and drop {orig_table}_old
7. Refresh view definition of 1:1 view to introduce identity column. (Optional)

Hope this helps.

Another solution that you can try if you need to expand the data type of a column that is outside of the allowable in place modification. (e.g. DECIMAL(3,0) -> DECIMAL(5,0)):

```
ALTER TABLE {MyTable} ADD {Orig_ColumnName}_New DECIMAL(5,0) NULL;
UPDATE {MyTable} SET {Orig_ColumnName}_New = {Orig_Column};
ALTER TABLE {MyTable} DROP {Orig_ColumnName};
ALTER TABLE {MyTable} RENAME {Orig_ColumnName}_New AS {Orig_ColumnName};
ALTER TABLE {MyTable} ADD {Orig_ColumnName} NOT NULL; /* If original column was NOT NULL */
```

The rules explaining the boundaries for expanding a columns data type can be found in the Teradata DDL manual.

Comment: I forgot the `Rename` option existed, else would have answered the question before you did ;)

Comment: You entire answer basically sums up the last paragraph in my question.  In short, the method you propose is the exact method I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin nope. the difference is in the downtime of the table. in the rename method, u have almost no downtime

Comment: But such a change is typically going to occur during a production deployment anyway when the expectation of downtime has been set.  Once all the scripts are put together and executed in the dev and staging environment (if one exists), it will only take a few seconds to execute the same scripts in the production environment.  Besides, the rename option is a mere commodity.  You still have to recreate the table just to add a column, something you shouldn't have to do imo.

Comment: But you are going to encounter other data model changes such as data type expansions that can not be completed on the existing table/column. In those instances you can either go through what I have listed above or add a new column with a different name and the correct data type. Then run an UPDATE against the table to move the data. Then submit an ALTER table against the table to drop the original column and then rename the new column as the old column. That is three locks against the table and a non-block level UPDATE of the table.

Comment: Not trying to be difficult, but I am not sure I understand. When you say "add a new column with a different name," that seems to suggests that I am trying to duplicate an existing column and delete the old so that the column I just created effectively becomes the old column. However, I am trying to add a completely new column, the likes of which currently does not exist in this table.  I want this new column to be an identity column, but I do not find it practical to painstakingly clone a table and its metadata just to basically add a column, especially when this table has 30+ fields.

Comment: Added reference to Teradata manual indicating that you simply can't do what you are trying to accomplish against an existing base table. I understand dealing with tables with many columns. (I'm working on tables with over a hundred columns for a production implementation this weekend.) You can script the SHOW TABLE commands to produce a flat file with the table definitions in them to make adding the column easier.

Comment: The SHOW command saved the day here.  With that, I am able to get the table create script that I can modify to add the identity column.  After that, it's mass inserts which are not a problem.  Thanks.